# Public profile link is not visible in dark mode

Tags: bug, profile-page, dark-mode

Public link is not properly visible if we have selected dark theme.

[image]

Comment: Already reported: [Developer Story inputs are too light and too dark](/a/396656/4642212). See [Dark Mode Beta: Complete list of reported feature requests and bugs](/a/396655/4642212).